# Horizontally lining up images and text on a Gatsby web-page

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

As part of a uni project, my team needs to develop an event listing web-page for a client. I've mocked up a design in adobe illustrator that the client likes and have spent the past day or so trying to turn the mock-up into code so that it looks the same on the webpage as it does in illustrator. I have tried a few different variations on how the list is layed out but the image disappears if I put it in a list element.

I am using Gatsby with the basic plugins

- gatsby-plugin-styled-components

```js
const eventCalendar = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <section className={styles.eventCalendar}>
        <li>
          <Image />
        </li>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>29th Aug 2020</li>
            <li>5km - 100km</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>BRIGHT RUNNING FESTIVAL</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Virtual</li>
          </ul>
          <button>Details</button>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default eventCalendar
```

```css
.eventCalendar {
  width: 100%;
}

.eventCalendar ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.eventCalendar li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.eventCalendar button {
  background: rgb(148, 88, 199);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(148, 88, 199, 1) 0%,
    rgba(92, 62, 183, 1) 100%
  );
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

- gatsby-transformer-sharp
- gatsby-plugin-sharp
- gatsby-source-filesystem

### This is what the mock up should look like

[image: Wireframe]

### This is what I have been able to code

[image: My Attempt]

### Here is the JavaScript

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Image from "../components/Images"
import styles from "../styles/event-calendar.module.css"

const eventCalendar = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <section className={styles.eventCalendar}>
        <li>
          <Image />
        </li>
        <ul>
          <ul>
            <li>29th Aug 2020</li>
            <li>5km - 100km</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>BRIGHT RUNNING FESTIVAL</li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>Virtual</li>
          </ul>
          <button>Details</button>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default eventCalendar
```

### Here is the CSS

```
.eventCalendar {
  width: 100%;
}

.eventCalendar ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.eventCalendar li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.eventCalendar button {
  background: rgb(148, 88, 199);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(148, 88, 199, 1) 0%,
    rgba(92, 62, 183, 1) 100%
  );
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

Comment: Create a demo of whatever you could code through CodeSandbox.

Comment: I am trying import the project into CodeSandbox but I am stuck permanently on 'Creating Repository'

Comment: Just edit your post and hit Ctrl-M, and you'll see how to enter a working example directly into your code. Makes it easier on all of us. :)

Comment: I've done it, but it just errors out and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Stackoverflow: How do I ask a good question? > How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Next time, "clean" your Q (Your issue not really related to react/gatsby/gatsby-plugin-styled-components => this is a `pure` CSS layout question).

Also, you should "fix" your markup (You use invalid `nested lists` HTML markup. <kbd>Copy paste</kbd> your HTML her: https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).

**Before**

```css
.eventCalendar {
  width: 100%;
}

.eventCalendar ul {
  text-align: left;
}

.eventCalendar li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 12px;
}

.eventCalendar button {
  background: rgb(148, 88, 199);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(148, 88, 199, 1) 0%,
    rgba(92, 62, 183, 1) 100%
  );
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <li>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/120" alt="thumb"/>
  </li>
  <ul class="eventCalendar">
    <ul>
      <li>29th Aug 2020</li>
      <li>5km - 100km</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>BRIGHT RUNNING FESTIVAL</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
      <li>Virtual</li>
    </ul>
    <button>Details</button>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**After**

One way to solve this is by [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

```css
.flex-wrapper{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

ul.eventCalendar{
  /* remove bullets */
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* nested flex grid */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.eventCalendar li{
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.eventCalendar .date{
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.eventCalendar .distance {
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.eventCalendar .name, .eventCalendar .location {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.thumb{
  padding: 7px;
}

.button_col{
  /* align the col to the right */
  margin-left: auto;
  /* v center the button */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  background: rgb(148, 88, 199);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(148, 88, 199, 1) 0%,
    rgba(92, 62, 183, 1) 100%
  );
  color: white;
  font-size: 24pt;
  min-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-wrapper">
  <div class="thumb">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/121" alt="thumb"/>
  </div>
  <ul class="eventCalendar">
    <li class="date">29th Aug 2020</li>
    <li class="distance">5km - 100km</li>
    <li class="name"><h2>Event Name</h2></li>
    <li class="location">Location (Place, State)</li>    
  </ul>
  <div class="button_col">
    <button class="btn">Details</button>  
  </div>
</section>
```

*** Add Media-Queries on small screens (To avoid "broken layout").
For example wrap (wrap onto multiple lines) on mobile.

```
/* MOBILE */
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .flex-wrapper{
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code didn't work for me. However I was able to figure out how to implement portions of it. Thanks

Comment: Only problem I am know facing is centring the button. When I use the code you supplied to centre the button, I only affect the text for some reason and have had no luck in even moving the button.